# What is this anime that was shown in Akira?

Tags: akira

What anime is this? [image: Akira Easter Egg]

I was watching some random akira videos and I found this easter egg that I never noticed before.  I remember seeing an opening of an 80s or older anime about some old police trio or something like that.Could it be possibly based off of this? [Manga Mito Kōmon](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5f4TbHji8II)

Answer (score 4):

It's almost certainly an outright reference to the well-known live-action show [Mito Komon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mito_K%C5%8Dmon).

> The title character is the historic Tokugawa Mitsukuni, former vice-shogun and retired second daimyo of the Mito Domain. In the guise of Mitsuemon, a retired crêpe merchant from Echigo, he roams the realm with two samurai retainers, fun-loving Sasaki Sukesaburō (Suke-san) and studious Atsumi Kakunoshin (Kaku-san). An episode typically starts with some injustice perpetrated by a corrupt official, wealthy merchant or gangster; the travelers arrive incognito, discover the injustice and quietly investigate it; and the episode concludes with a brawl in which the unarmed, disguised protagonists better a crowd of samurai and gangsters, culminating with the presentation of the inrō that reveals the hero's identity.

I wasn't aware there was an animated version.  Mito Komon has been around for decades (1969-2011, over 1200 episodes), like their own version of Doctor Who.

Since it's a well-known part of pop-culture, the show is often referenced or outright parodied, [like in Samurai Champloo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZaPqA0Mobwc) (Mugen, it'll be our little secret....).